# How to make a multiple recyclerViews which contains posts recyclerview and stories recyclerView similar to facebook app?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to make something like below:

On that screenshot of facebook lite app:

[image]

**At part marked "1":** is a vertical recyclerview which contains posts.

**At part marked "2":** is a horizontal recyclerview which contains the stories.

**At part marked "3":** is the same recyclerview as at part marked "1" which contains posts.

I have already made the recyclerview for posts and It works well. Now I want to know how should I make the recyclerview for stories or friendship suggestion and make the two recyclerviews appear like on Facebook app ?

How could I have recyclerviews similar to the one in facebook app ?

Facebook show multiples recyclerViews One vertical where it shows the posts some others horizontal  where it
shows stories or sometimes friendship suggestion.

Do you undestand me ?

Please tell me if I should explain more my issue.

Thanks.

Comment: What I think they do is that randomly or intentionally place RecyclerView with Horizontal layout as one of the children from the RecyclerView that shows children vertically. This can be achieved in an adapter but I am not really sure about this.

Answer (score 0):

you can define different View Holders for a Recycler List

the horizontal lists are just a view holder with another recycler inside them but with horizontal orientation in the main list. you can choose which view holder you want to use in OnCreatViewHolder

Answer (score 0):

You should implement `RecyclerView` with `multi-view` type which gives you the various layout on a single RecyclerView adapter.
By doing this you need a model class which should have a field for define the different type.

Please have a look below sample code

Sample Model class

```
data class Sample(
    var a: String = ""
    ...
    var type: String = ""
)
```

Field **type** in model class above will define a unique **view-type** of adapter

Sample Adapter Class

```
class SampleAdapter(
    private val context: Context,
    private val items: ArrayList<Sample>
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {
    companion object {
        private const val HEADER = 1
        private const val STORY = 2
        private const val FEED = 3
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return when(items[position].type) {
            Constant.HEADER -> HEADER
            Constant.STORY -> STORY
            else -> FEED
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = items.size
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        return when(viewType) {
            HEADER -> HeaderViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout_header, parent, false))
            STORY -> StoryViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout_story, parent, false))
            else -> FeedViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout_feed, parent, false))
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        when(holder) {
            is HeaderViewHolder -> holder.onBind()
            is StoryViewHolder -> holder.onBind()
            is FeedViewHolder -> holder.onBind()
        }
    }
    
    inner class HeaderViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        fun onBind() {
            ....your business logic
        }
    }
    inner class StoryViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        fun onBind() {
            ....your business logic
        }
    }
    inner class FeedViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        fun onBind() {
            ....your business logic
        }
    }
}
```

And when you are using the above adapter in `Activity` or `Fragment`. You should define the type of each item in `ArrayList`

For example: `samples.add(Sample(...., type=Constant.Header))`

Comment: I'm not asking About recyclerview multiple view type. I want To put recyclerview inside another recyclerview.  Do you understand me ?

Comment: You can use nested Recyclerview. Please refer to this link for implementation: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-a-nested-recyclerview-in-android/